# Obtain Bundle Identifier programmatically

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

How can I obtain a string of the Bundle Identifier programmatically from within my App?

Answer (score 470, accepted):

Objective-C

```
NSString *bundleIdentifier = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
```

Swift 1.2

```
let bundleIdentifier = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier
```

Swift 3.0

```
let bundleIdentifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier
```

Xamarin.iOS

```
var bundleIdentifier = NSBundle.MainBundle.BundleIdentifier
```

Comment: This answer is not limited to iOS. It works for Mac apps too.

Comment: In Swift, use `let bundleIdentifier = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier`

Comment: (you can delete this comment) but I love the feeling of reading the answer then in the comment, see something like @Jonny s and Tim (although you can see this in another whole answer), it links to something else that still relevant and useful. Thanks for great community guys.

Comment: Swift3: `Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!`

Answer (score 50):

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
```

([documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/bundleIdentifier))

Comment: In Swift, use `let bundleIdentifier = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier`

Answer (score 3):

You may need Core Foundation approach to get the value. ARC example is following:

```
NSString *value = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(CFBundleGetInfoDictionary(CFBundleGetMainBundle()),
                                                                     (const void *)(@"CFBundleIdentifier"));
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the bundle identifier programmatically in **Swift 3.0**:

> **Swift 3.0**

```
let bundle = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier
```

Answer (score 1):

f you are trying to get it programmatically , you can use below line of code :

Objective-C:

```
NSString *bundleIdentifier = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
```

Swift 3.0 :

```
let bundleIdentifier =  Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier
```

Updated for latest swift It will work for both iOS and Mac apps.

Answer (score 0):

I use these macros to make it much shorter:

```
#define BUNDLEID    [NSString stringWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]]

#define BUNDLEIDEQUALS(bundleIdString) [BUNDLEID isEqualToString:bundleIdString]
```

so I can just compare like this:

```
if (BUNDLEIDEQUALS(@"com.mycompany.myapp") {
    //do this
}
```