# How can I inspect elements on native iOS application

Tags: ios, inspect

I am running an iOS native app on iOS Simulator and would like to inspect the elements on the app to get the ID.

Does anyone knows how this can be done?

*Note:* Please, this question is for iOS native App not Web based app!

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: What elements are you referring to?  Have you tried something already?

Comment: https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCIntrospect is pretty nice

Comment: Which ID are you trying to get?

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you may be looking for something like Firebug or the Chrome Inspector for your native app? I'm not sure what you mean by "ID". Interface elements in iOS don't really have IDs the same way DOM elements have IDs.

You should check out the Spark Inspector (http://www.sparkinspector.com/), which allows you to see the views of your app and modify them at runtime - it may help you see what you're looking for. Full disclosure: I am the author of the app ;-)

Comment: This is pure awesomeness.Thank you for making my life easy. :)

Comment: Is it possible to do "WebInspector" on WkWebView (http://stackoverflow.com/q/34927983/730807)

Comment: Does it support XCode 8 & iOS 10?

Comment: you're awesomeeee. Any thoughts if I can get a similar app for android?

Answer (score 0):

There is a new app, called Reveal, that does an incredible job.
Not only you can check view's properties, you can also view all the app in a "exploded" 3D view, change the sizes and properties.
Specially for iOS 7, where the view controller starts from the beginning of the screen (and not below the navigation bar), it can be really useful.

You can download the trial at http://revealapp.com and decide which license you should get.

Answer (score 0):

There are two Best ways for this -

1. Use Accessibility Inspector which is Apples's inbuilt tool so you don't need any other support .
2. As you will be using Xcode mostly for you code part, there is an option to play UI recording which capture all the actions and elements that you interact with on native app.

Answer (score -1):

You need to inspect the App's Bundle.

Check this answer on stackoverflow, to get the appID: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8883166/933887

Comment: I am not clear what you meant by inspecting the app#s bundle.       I am running an automation test using monkey talk, However monkey talk for one reason or the order is unable to identify an ID which i selected when recording. I would like to inspect a button on the app to get the ID e.g with firebug you can inspect an element and extract the ID

Comment: I suggest stating exactly what you need in your question. As it currently worded most people are going to assume you are trying to access the appId view native code. Not a scripting language

Comment: Also I suggest using xCodes built in Automation testing(Using Instruments), which you write using JScript. You can also record your actions and it will write the code for you, which you then go through and fine tune.

Answer (score -1):

Appium has an inspector for ios applications.
This is the link for appium: http://appium.io/
and in this video you can see the inspector in action: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jQZTRz2W9xg