# Why INSPECT ELEMENT or WEB INSPECTOR or developerExtrasEnabled (WkWebView) is not working in iOS While its working for OSX

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, web-inspector, wkwebviewconfiguration

Here is the code snippet that facilitates the INSPECT ELEMENT in WkWebView

```
preferences.setValue(true, forKey:"developerExtrasEnabled")
```

Here is the screenshot of INSPECT ELEMENT working in OSX(right click)

[image: OSx inspect element]

*Right click is equivalent to Tap & Hold in iOS* But I am not able to see anything like I see in OSX

Here is the [complete code](http://justpaste.it/qqn6) if anybody wants to try

Comment: Are you sure that's how WKWebView is supposed to work on iOS? Normally to inspect webviews you need to plug the phone into your mac and inspect it through the Safari Develop menu.

Comment: It's a completely different OS, there's no concept of right click on iOS. Check this answer for inspecting webviews http://stackoverflow.com/a/12552686/488611

Comment: @JamesP - Thanks for sharing the link

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its not possible to do in iOS as
**WKPreference** is not **key value coding-compliant** for the key **developerExtrasEnabled** so we can't do this using this approach.