# Storyboard reference to cocoapods storyboard seems broken

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, xcode-storyboard, storyboard-reference

I have a project called "ViewTester" with a cocoapod linked to it called "blub"

[image: project structure]

Now in the main.storyboard i want to reference blubstory.storyboard like so:
[image: Storyboard reference]

Properties of the storyboard reference:
[image]

BundleID of ViewTester:
[image]

BundleID of blub:
[image]

When i try to run this i get the following exception:
[image]

I saw a related stackoverflow post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783325/using-a-storyboard-reference-to-a-storyboard-in-a-different-project-bundle-appea), but the answer did not resolve the issue as there are is no target membership for "blub" in main.storyboard

[image]

Any ideas / solutions on this issue? To me it seems like a bug in storyboard referencing as it doesn't look for the storyboard in the "blub" bundle.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I solved this by changing the bundle identifier on the storyboard reference:

[image]

Appearantly the bundle identifier does get taken into consideration by the storyboard reference.  It's just that when it is not OK it prints out a really weird non informative exception, like the one in my question above. If your bundle ID is correct it will work!

Also: when cocoapods adds your pod to another project it creates a target of your pod with the bundle identifier **"org.cocoapods.your_pod_name_here"** instead of your bundle identifier!

Comment: Glad you found a solution! It surprises me that the bundle identifier is a freeform string property. This sort of problem would be avoidable if it were a combo box (like the Storyboard property above it) populated with known bundle identifiers in the project. I'm repurposing your bug (radar://26267206) for this enhancement.

Comment: How the HELL did you find that?! Thanks a lot, it saved my day.

Comment: @Martin So basically, this was the subject of my master thesis and I simply HAD TO GET IT DONE before (then) next week. So i tried everything and anything in a coffee infused rampage and luckily it worked :)