# Using a storyboard reference in a different project Could not find a storyboard in bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ipad

> Could not find a storyboard named 'Storyboard' in bundle NSBundle

This Exception came when I try to segue from one storyboard to another in second Project in workspace (I have two projects in **WorkSpace**). How to connect the storyboards?

[image]

Comment: That's seems tricky, is your 2nd project is being used as framework in first project?

Comment: Every file is associated with a bundle, the main bundle is the bundle of the application and other frameworks etc. have their own bundle. The error you're getting states that the stroyboard you're trying to access is not present in the bundle.

Comment: The storyBoard I want to access is in sub Project. and from Main Project i am accessing. ( these two projects are in workPlace) . Simply I want to ask ( In workPlace how to go from one Main Projects storyBoard to Another projects story Board)

Comment: Either code for it (load the storyboard from another bundle and then push/present) or include (membership) that story board in your first project

Comment: i copied the story Board in Main Project, Then its work fine, but i need to run both projects separately, How I can get access of sub project. becoz i initially in Main Project. when i run project then Main Project storyBoard start. How to get access of sub project.

Comment: My issue is same like in this link below
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783325/using-a-storyboard-reference-to-a-storyboard-in-a-different-project-bundle-appea

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the other Storyboard file to your target (Ticking Target membership check-box)? You can find it in your **File Inspector**:

[image: Storyboard target membership]

Comment: i Added the image in my question,  this is the **Target** of Main Story Board  (First Project) . I am doing Segue with Referencing view controller.  the targeted story board is in second project.  I checked 2 check box in Target Membership, but same error

Comment: My Issues is same like in this link below
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783325/using-a-storyboard-reference-to-a-storyboard-in-a-different-project-bundle-appea